# NullPointerException with setAdapter - Trying to set array adapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to set array adapter and have following code in place:

```
private String[] mServices;
private ListView mDrawerList;
//Ends Here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //For Navigation Drawer
    mServices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_services);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mServices));
```

The last line of code where I am trying to set Adapter, I get a NullPointerException. The app crashes if I try to navigate to page containing this code.

Any pointers?

Here's the debug:

`07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parrot.urlripper/com.parrot.urlripper.google}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at com.parrot.urlripper.google.onCreate(google.java:35)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-08 20:05:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)`

Comment: post (and read, while you're at it) the stacktrace.

Comment: stacktrace would help

Comment: make sure you are inflating the correct view

Comment: have you debug..?? show your logcat

Comment: "Any pointers?"  - Yes, use IDE and put a breakpoint and see whats wrong.

Comment: @SilentKiller Added the debug info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor of ArrayAdapter, you have to pass a TextView id as described in the Android documentation : 
[ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29)

There is some tutorial on internet about this subject, for example this one : [ArrayAdapter basic tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1516)

And your problem could also come from the `mServices` which can be null.

---

EDIT:

The following code works for me:

The Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] mServices = new String[] {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"};
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text_view, mServices));
    }
}
```

The activity_main.xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the text_view.xml file:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="italic">
</TextView>
```

Comment: mServices is a string array defined in Strings xml. And The first parameter requires a Context, which in this case is the base application. The link you shared replicates what I have done.

Comment: Yes but the second parameter has to be a ressource id which directly points onto a TextView. In the tutorial I have shared, he used "android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1" which is an xml file with only one TextView field  (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_expandable_list_item_1.xml)

Comment: I have a drawer_list_item.xml with following code: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="italic" >
    

</TextView>`
This is being reference above.

Comment: Maybe you need an id for your TextView. Your error has to be here (if it's the right line pointed by the Exception) cause apparently you checked the mServices object. So your problem is your id, to be sure, you can try to use the "android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1" id.

Comment: @grattmandu003 Yes, id was missing. Included that attribute and tried with "android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1" but still doesn't work. I am still learning android programming but by the looks of it, the Context field seems to be creating this issues. Also, if I comment out the last line of code, then the activity loads without any error.

Comment: It's really weird, cause a "this" cannot be null. Try with "YourActivityName.this" instead of "this" but I think it won't work.
I can't test some code right now, I will do it in few hours and come back to you.

Comment: I tried the following alternatives: this, MainActivity.this, getApplicationContext(), getBaseContext(). None of them seem to work. I know this is not a good way of debugging but I am really puzzled.

Comment: Tried that. The core problem is I have similar code in MainActivity however when I move to a different activity using Intent and then use same implementation to go to another activity then I get the error stated above. Anyhow, your response is correct nonetheless. Also, i have shifted to using fragments rather than creating new activity.

Comment: Ok, glad you have found a way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this line .

mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, {"test","test","test"}));

if this solves your problem than ,than mServices array is the problem ..

Comment: Tried it. Still the same issue. The mServices string array is defined in Strings xml file. I used this code setup is the MainActivity and it works without any issue. But when I click for this activity, I get the above mentioned error.